# Update embed messages every 5 minutes (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted my bot to update his embed message every 5 minutes for ever, is that possible?

Like I do !update-message

And my bots sends the message programmed for example
Title: Numbers
Description: This message updates every 5 minutes
Add field:  name: Number ; value: str(num)

num=0
num=num+1 # How it gets bigger

Comment: Direct answer : Yes it is,
Further answer : Please update your question with further informations of what you want.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Client.edit_message see official docs

Comment: Care @Joel this is the `latest` doc, maybe he's using `rewrite` (and there's good chances. Also he pretty much want infos about the `background_task` feature from `asyncio` (as in what i told in my answer))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can look at [that](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py).

Then, here's how i would do it. Adapt it to your need (also, note that this is code from the `rewrite` branch. If you're using `latest` i really much advice you to [migrate](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html) to `rewrite` as `latest` is deprecated anyway and its developpement is in standby)
:

```py
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        message = await client.get_channel(channelId).fetch_message(messageId)
        await message.edit(embed = newEmbed)
        await asyncio.sleep(300)

bg_task = client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
```

**NB** : Don't forget to replace `channelId` by the id of the channel the message is in, `messageId` by the id of the message you want to edit and `newEmbed` by the changed embed

Comment: If dosent change the text

Comment: what ? if you want to change the text, change the text , if you want to change the embed, change the embed. look at [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.edit) to see a list of everything you can edit.