# Auto Updating Discord Embed ? discord .py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that displays the current packets per second of my VPS in an embed, i want it to update about every 1 second. any ideas on how i could do this using discord.py? I already have a way to display the packets per second, but i just need it to be updated every 1 second.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your current attempts to solve the problem? What's the issue with them? SO is not a site were we write code for others, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update embed messages every 5 minutes (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393352/update-embed-messages-every-5-minutes-discord-py)

Comment: That is outdated @Xiddoc tasks is used now

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).

You would create a task with and store the guild, channel and message ID as variables.

However, you will reach a rate limit so it's recommended to do it every 5-15 seconds instead.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
async def get_packets_task():
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(GUILD)
    channel = guild.get_channel(CHANNEL)
    message = channel.get_message(MESSAGE)
    await message.edit("packet")
```